# Excel.Application.get_Item not working

Tags: vb.net, excel

I was looking for a way to check if an Excel File was opened and the solutions I found were more or less this function

[Function using get_Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLGw4.png)

Yet this method gives me an error

[List of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDqWy.png)

That's "'get_Item' is not a member of 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks'."

What am I missing? I've seen this method a couple times in different solutions

(I'm using Excel 2013)

Comment: That's old C# syntax, necessary before it supported indexed properties.  In VB.NET code you use app.WorkBooks(name), in modern C# code you use app.WorkBooks[name].  Use the proper tag please, clearly you are using VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant stated, instead of using

Excel.Application.get_Item

You should use

app.WorkBooks(name)